# TYPO3: Run scheduler task from extbase controller in frontend

Tags: typo3, scheduler, typo3-extensions

The scheduler task is normally executed via the command line script /typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3 scheduler:run.

Is it possible to call the task inside/with a frontend controller from an extbase extension?
(as it is, from the backend module "Scheduler" by clicking "Execute selected tasks")

The goal is to run the task on every pageview of a specific page. (cache disabled)

(No exec/shell_exec available)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheduler run script is a Symfony Command Controller. You can run it in your Controller using the following code:

```php
$schedulerCommand = new \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Command\SchedulerCommand();
$schedulerInput = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput([]);
$schedulerOutput = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput();
$schedulerCommand->run($schedulerInput, $schedulerOutput);
```

Depending on which tasks you execute, it can take a while to execute and you might run into timeouts.

Comment: Maybe it's an option to modify an entry of `tx_scheduler_task` and execute it via the next cron.

Comment: @JulianHofmann I assumed there was no cron set. If there is, then yes, you should probably set the `nextexecution` field to the current timestamp in `tx_scheduler_task` so it is executed when the cron is called next.